# How to process large amounts of REST API calls?

Tags: php, api

I have to export a site with hundreds of thousands of records through REST API calls.

I got all the record IDs that I need to retrieve stored in a mysql db. I have a PHP script get the next ID, make the API call using curl, save the data, mark the ID as complete and then use a  to reload the page.

That's kind of slow. Any ideas of how to speed it up?

Comment: Load a batch of them every time? Say like 10 or 100?

Comment: Did @RedHydra's answer help you? It certainly helped me. Why not accept it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately trying to emulate thread level parallelism (or really any level of parallelism) is.... ridiculously annoying in PHP. Fortunately, for your particular use case you just need http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php

It essentially executes multiple curl handles in parallel (at least the I/O of retrieving the html contents of the page). The example provided in the docs is decent I think, let me know if you need any further help.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Todas url gravadas em array
$url[] = 'http://www.link1.com.br';
$url[] = 'https://www.link2.com.br';
$url[] = 'https://www.link3.com.br';

// Setando opção padrão para todas url e adicionando a fila para processamento
$mh = curl_multi_init();
foreach($url as $key => $value){
  $ch[$key] = curl_init($value);
  curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
  curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  
  curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch[$key]);
}

// Executando consulta
do {
  curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
  curl_multi_select($mh);
} while ($running > 0);

// Obtendo dados de todas as consultas e retirando da fila
foreach(array_keys($ch) as $key){
  echo curl_getinfo($ch[$key], CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  echo curl_getinfo($ch[$key], CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
  echo "\n";
  
  curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch[$key]);
}

// Finalizando
curl_multi_close($mh);
```